# Only return specified associated model from sequelize junction model

Tags: node.js, postgresql, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo

I'm trying to properly use sequelize queries to work with graphql + apollo.

Here is my `Pool` gql schema:

```
  type Pool {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    createdBy: User
    members: [User]
  }
```

Here is the pool model association

```
  Pool.associate = models => {
    Pool.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      through: models.UserPool,
      foreignKey: models.UserPool.poolId,
    })
  }
```

Likewise for `User`
Schema:

```
  type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    email: String!
    role: String
  }
```

model assoc

```
  User.associate = models => {
    User.belongsToMany(models.Pool, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      through: models.UserPool,
      foreignKey: 'userId',
    })
  }
```

So these two models have a n:m association through a junction model called
`UserPool` which just stores the pks for `User` and `Pool`.

In my `./resolvers/pool.js` I'm defining my gql model resolver for `Pool`. 
This is where my issue is. 
in the below `members` field I simply want to return an array of the `User` 
object, which I can access through `UserPool`

```
  Pool: {
    createdBy: async (pool, _, { models }) => {
      // this sequelize built-in works and returns the createdBy User model
      const user = await pool.getUser()
      return user
    },
    members: async (pool, _, { models }) => {
      let users = []

      const poolUsers = await models.UserPool.findAll({
        where: { poolId: pool.id },
      })


      // *** below is what I want to do -- use the in-built ***
      // *** sequelize query methods you get with the n:m assoc ***

      const users = await poolUsers.getUsers()

      // However, each time this throws an error: 
      // getUsers() is not a function....

      return users
    },
  },
```

Just to cover my bases too, here's my UserPool model association def:

```
  UserPool.associate = models => {
    UserPool.belongsTo(models.User, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      foreignKey: 'userId',
    })
    UserPool.belongsTo(models.Pool, {
      onDelete: 'CASCADE',
      foreignKey: 'poolId',
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`poolUsers` is an array of UserPool objects, so it doesn't have a `getUsers` method. You could map over each UserPool and get the users, but this will result in an unnecessarily large number of calls to your database.

You've created an association between `Pool` and `User`. So instead you can just do

```
members: async (pool) => {
  return pool.getUsers()      
}
```

Comment: I actually just realized this. I defined an extraneous association in my `models/pool.js` file :facepalm:
But yes, this is correct.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the auto methods in Sequelize, but they did not seem to work.

You can just do:

```
models.User.findAll({
        include: [{
            model: models.UserPool,
            where: { poolId: pool.id },
            required: true
        }]
```